# Constantly Returning True

Tags: objective-c, boolean

For some reason my boolean seems to be returning true, even when the else should be getting called during testing:

```
if([photoId isEqualToString:object]) {
    liked = TRUE;
    cell.likedButton.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"likedBtn.png"];
    break;
} else {
    liked = FALSE;
    cell.likedButton.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"likeBtn.png"];
}
```

To clarify a little more, photoId is sometimes equal to the object. But in one case, it isn't equal to it. The images in my cell are changing to the right files contingent on the equal method however, the boolean seems to only return yes.

Any ideas why this is happening? Does it have something to do with my break?

Comment: Log `photoId` and `object` before the `if` statements.

Comment: Are they both strings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should only put a `break` statement when you want to terminate a loop. Perhaps you're running this conditional inside a loop so once the statement is TRUE, your entire loop stops (break).

Answer (score 0):

Since it is in a loop it is breaking after the first time it is true. You should put the break in the else statement if you want it to break if it is false.

Comment: It is. Further up in the code its a loop. I didn't show that section. However, I think I found the problem. How do I make it so that I have a boolean for the specific cell?

Comment: Wyatt. Got it. I think I found my problem here. I need to figure out if it's true or false for a specific cell. It seems like it's just logging the last result of the boolean before it breaks. If that makes sense?

Comment: Exactly: the value of the last thing before the break is being logged and it is getting cut off too early. You will want to move the break. I hope this has answered your question. Please select my answer, and good luck!